# Using setInterval into another Setinterval

Tags: jquery, html, css, setinterval

Hi Friends i want to run my code with only using one `setInterval` function. Currently I am using two `setInterval's` to achieve my goal can we get same result with using only one 'setInterval' for your reff pleaase go to this link **http://jsfiddle.net/msUyh/** and i have also mentioned my code below

**script**

```
    setInterval(function () {
        $('div').css('display', 'none');
    }, 5000);

    var num = 2;
$('div').append('1<br/>')
    setInterval(function () {
        if (num <= 5) {
            $('div').append(num + '<br/>')
            num++;
        }
    }, 1000)
```

**CSS**

```
body, html{height:100%;}
div
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000; 
  display:block;
  font:15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: You're not stopping your interval anywhere?

Comment: see is like this way which i mention in my answer thanks @Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add some extra conditions in your original setInterval

```
var num = 2;
$('div').append('1<br/>')
setInterval(function () {
    if (num <= 5) {
        $('div').append(num + '<br/>')
        num++;
    } else if (num < 6) {
        num++;
    } else {
        $('div').css('display', 'none');
    }
}, 1000)
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/msUyh/1/)

Since you are not mentioning clearing the interval i assume you may be considering using this in an ongoing fashion like the following fiddle.

[Repeating Counter](http://jsfiddle.net/msUyh/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
 var num = 2;
    $('div').append('1<br/>')
    var setint=    setInterval(function () {

            if (num <= 5) {
                $('div').append(num + '<br/>')
                num++;
            }else{
            $('div').css('display', 'none');
            clearInterval(setint);
           }    
        }, 1000)
```